# Constructing context free grammar with a number constraint to one of the elements in the language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, regular-expressions

How do I determine the rules of a context free grammar when there is a constraint on one of the elements?

For example over the alphabet {0, 1} containing all words with at most three 1s?

I have the following but seems the production rules could be much more succinct, any ideas?

```
 S -> X1X1X1X
 S -> X1X1X
 S -> X1X
 S -> X
 X -> 0X
 X -> e
```

e is epsilon

Comment: The language you consider is regular. So, yes, the grammar could be simpler.

Comment: how can I code this as a production rule without explicitly the repeating the  production rules with the different number of terminal values?

Comment: @j.-e. How so? A right-regular grammar for this language will be a little different, but I don't see how it will be simpler.

Comment: @MJD I am referring to the Chomsky hierarchy. This language can be generated by a right-regular grammar. The grammar proposed by the OP is context-free, but not regular.

Comment: How would I make this simpler?

Answer (score 0):

For regular languages like these, I like to imagine reading the string from left to right and keeping track of how many ones I've seen so far. Let the symbols $A,B,C,D$ represent a state where you've seen zero, one, two, or three 1s so far.

Then a grammar for your language is:

\begin{align*}
A &\mapsto \epsilon \;|\; 0A \;|\; 1B \\
B &\mapsto \epsilon \;|\; 0B \;|\; 1C \\
C &\mapsto \epsilon \;|\; 0C \;|\; 1D \\
D &\mapsto \epsilon \;|\; 0D 
\end{align*}